# From a string of 3 numbers to 3 integers

Tags: beginner, parsing, integer, rust

I'm solving [some puzzles](http://adventofcode.com/) to learn Rust. A problem I faced is to turn a string of 3 integers into 3 integers. I succeeded with the following example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut it = "   455   123   42  ".split_whitespace();
    let (a, b, c) = match (it.next(), it.next(), it.next()) {
        (Some(a), Some(b), Some(c)) => {
            (a.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
             b.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
             c.parse::<i32>().unwrap())
        }
        _ => panic!("Oops"),
    };

    println!("{:?}", (a, b, c));
}
```

However, this code appears to have bad quality:

- bad error handling
- does not scale (works only for 3) with `N` integers.

How can I improve this code?

Comment: I don't know Rust, but try **iterating** over the **list** of strings (search keywords in bold).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write the code as

```
fn main() {
    let input = "   455   123   42  ";

    let numbers: Result<Vec<i32>, _> = input
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(str::parse)
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, iterators are very idiomatic in Rust. The [`Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) is the main documentation to check out. Once you have an iterator, such as by calling `split_whitespace`, you can do powerful things.

In this case, we can [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) a closure or a function across each element in the iterator, converting it from one type to another. Although we could have used `map(|the_string| the_string.parse())`, I prefer the shorter form of syntax when I can use it.

We converted each element using [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), which returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), one of Rust's main error handling types. At this point, each element from the iterator will be a `Result`, but we don't know what type it is yet! `parse` is powerful in that you can parse to many types, but that power comes at a cost — you have to specify what type you want to parse to. In the original code, the *turbofish* operator was used (`::<>`), but I'm not the biggest fan of the fish.

After all this code, we haven't really *done* anything yet. Rust iterators don't do anything until you pull values from them via [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next). We could call `next` over and over ourselves, but in this case I'd like a collection of all the values. That's where [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) comes into play.

Similar to `str::parse`, `collect` allows the *caller* to specify what type should be collected into. This allows us to collect into a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) or a [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) or [many other types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). In this case, we can collect into `Result`. If any of the iterator values were invalid, the entire collection will be invalid with the first found error. Otherwise, we will construct a `Vec`. Here is where we finally specify what type to parse into as well: an `i32`. We leave the error type up to the compiler by using the underscore `_`; once we have specified what kind of type to parse to, we also specify the error type.

To wrap it all up, we print the value to the user using the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) formatter. This will show us if the `Result` was an `Ok` with the entire vector of values or an `Err` along with the error itself.

---

> bad error handling

I'd point out that your original code has more error handling compared to many other languages, just because of Rust. For example, each call to `unwrap` or `panic` is error handling that other languages might have deferred to runtime (or never!). You handled the cases of the iterator being too short (although see below) as well as when the number failed to parse.

Your error *reporting* mechanism is fairly basic: the program ends when an error is encountered. There's **nothing wrong with that** though. It's far better than continuing on when you don't know how to!

---

As a side note, it's undefined behavior what the result of calling `Iterator::next` *after* it returns `None` the first time. The iterator is free to return nonsense values. If you need to call an `next` multiple times without checking the value in between each call, you should [`fuse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse) the iterator, ensuring it will always return `None` after the first `None`.